# Mysql передать поле при создании строки

Tags: mysql

Имеется 2 таблицы они связаны, но необходимо что бы когда при добавлении новой строки он обратился к первой таблице и по id строки передал определенную строку во вторую таблицу

что то на подобии такого но в автоматическом формате.

```
INSERT INTO trooms(`hotelsname`) SELECT hotelname FROM `thotels` WHERE id = 80
```

Прошу оказать помощь в данной проблеме. 
Заранее благодарен

Comment: А зачем вам это ? что за id строки такой, откуда он берется. Если у вас одна таблица ссылается на другую по id и при этом надо в нее же затянуть какое то значение из родительской таблицы - то у вас неверная модель базы, она нарушает вторую нормальную форму. А вообще "автоматически" - это значит триггерами

Comment: Суть в чём, у меня есть база с названием отелей thotels и есть база комнат trooms. И мне нужно сделать что бы когда я добавлял комнату её нужно привязать к определённому отелю, что бы когда открывали страницу того отеля отображались только его комнаты.

Comment: А зачем вам куда то вставлять название отеля кроме как в саму таблицу отелей ? Вы в комнатах держите id отеля и по этому id показываете все комнаты относящиеся к нужному вам отелю